# Error in copying data from one file to other

Tags: c

I want to copy the data from one file to other. But only one byte is copying.

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main() {
   FILE *fp1, *fp2;
   char a;

   fp1 = fopen("test.jpg", "r");
   if (fp1 == NULL) {
      puts("cannot open this file");
      exit(1);
   }

   fp2 = fopen("test1.jpg", "w+");
   if (fp2 == NULL) {
      puts("Not able to open this file");
      fclose(fp1);
      exit(1);
   }

   do {
      a = fgetc(fp1);
      fputc(a, fp2);
   } while (a != EOF);

   fcloseall();
}
```

test.jpg consists of data ff d8 32 86 ..... But it is copying only ff and coming out of the while loop. Is i am doing any thing wrong

Comment: Technically, this is undefined behavior.

Comment: 1)`char a;` -> `int a;` 2) use open mode "rb" and "wb" 3)check `EOF` before `fputc(a, fp2);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare `a` as `int`, not `char`.

```
int a;
```

Otherwise, that first `0xFF` gets expanded into `-1` (`EOF`).

You should also open/close the files with `b` (for "binary"):

```
fp1 = fopen("test.jpg", "rb");

// ...

fp2 = fopen("test1.jpg", "w+b");
```

And, as Drew noted, check `EOF` *before* writing the character:

```
while ((a = fgetc(fp1)) != EOF) {
  fputc(a, fp2);
}
```

Comment: Also, the `a != EOF` check should happen before `fputc`, not after

Comment: Ahh... reminds of the superior error density that only C can provide.